# Custom Web Part Properties in SharePoint 2010 Visual Web Parts-How to set it different for each user login

Tags: custom-web-part-property

I have custom webpart properties for a visual webpart. [This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/d52e2e1b-5938-43c0-9708-8d9d710880ae) helped me develop the custom webpart properties.

Now my issue is once a user sets the custom property it gets applied for all users, i want to limit it to user preference hence it should be different for every login.

How to set webpart property different for every login. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting PersonalizationScope.User on the property

```
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User),
WebBrowsable(true),
WebDisplayName("MyProperty")]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```